# UITableview Grouped Sections

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsrange

I'm trying to create a grouped sectioned tableview with this format:

> ```
>   Town Name
>
>       -Shop Name
>       -Shop Name
>
>
>   Second Town Name
>       -Shop Name  
>       -Shop Name
> ```

I have all the shop names stored in one nsmutablearray which is gathered from the net.
The town names are stored in a nsmutablearray also gathered from the net.

How do I split the shop names array into a subarray of the correct size so that I can display it under the correct town name in cellforrowatindexpath?

Please see my first post and code here for more detail: [iPhone SDK: Grouped UITableView Sections, List Items not showing under correct section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802295/iphone-sdk-grouped-uitableview-sections-list-items-not-showing-under-correct-s)

Comment: How is the shop array structure. Is it only NSStrings with the shop names?

Comment: Yes, it's just a list of the shop names

Comment: You must have some kind of connection between the shops and the towns ..